# Equilvalence point in redox Titration of Fe(II) and Fe(III) with Reinhardt-Zimmermann solution

Tags: redox, titration, iron

In the lab at university, we need to conduct a simultaneous determination of iron(II) and iron (III) ions using potassium permanganate solution.

In the first step, we just fill up our given sample solution to 100ml, and take 20 ml of it and fill it into an Erlenmeyer flask. Then we add 10ml of Reinhardt-Zimmermann-solution into the flask (my best guess is that our sample solution has hydrochloric acid in addition to iron (II) and iron (III)) and need to titrate with KMnO4-solution (1/50M) until the solution in the flask displays a very faint pink color. (determination of Fe(II))

The titration to determine Fe(III) is analogous, only that we need to reduce it beforehand.

But my problem is that I have a really difficult time recognizing red or pink colors (I have a condition), and when I did it the first time I didn't correctly identify the equivalence point. (Partly because the faint pink also discolours after a certain amount of time.)

My question is, if there is another indicator or extra chemical that I could add to the solution that makes the equivalence point easier to see and doesn't influence the reaction by a lot, the titration needs to be quantitative. I would appreciate any tips or help.

Comment: What about the [ferroin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroin) redox indicator, provided commertialy AFAIK ?  *Ferroin is the chemical compound with the formula [Fe(o-phen)3]SO4, where o-phen is an abbreviation for 1,10-phenanthroline, a bidentate ligand. The term "ferroin" is used loosely and includes salts of other anions such as chloride.* // Reduced = intense red, oxidized = blue // Eventually, using o-phen itself, if available

Comment: The Zimmermann-Reinhardt solution has no chemical use in this titration. It is simply added in order to make a colorless complex with $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ ions. This ferric ion is slightly colored brown - yellow. The end point is difficult to observe, without this Z-R solution, because it is not easy to see the first appearance of a pink color in a brownish solution. It is much better to observe this pink color if the solution is colorless.

Comment: Very good idea Poutnik. Indeed, when dissolved in 1M H2SO4 ferroin should have a redox potential of 1.07V which would be between Fe and permanganate, so after all the iron is oxidized it should oxidize the indicator